# Why does the client sees himself falling through the ground?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

Recently I tried making a multiplayer game and I have some problems. After I click "Play" in the menu and I get placed in the multiplayer scene, I see myself falling through the ground, and when I check the "Scene" tab in unity my character is standing where it should be and responds to my movements (as a player, all I can see is the infinite nothing around me but I can still look around, move, etc). When another player connects, he is bugged into the ground (and I can see the shadow from the other player that is hosting and plays directly from unity) and I can't move at all.

Code :

So in the main menu scene, I have this :
[image: main menu]

`NetworkController` script :

```
using Photon.Pun;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NetworkController : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
void Start()
{
    PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
}

public override void OnConnectedToMaster () {
    Debug.Log("coonnected to " + PhotonNetwork.CloudRegion + " server !");
}
void Update()
{
    
}
}
```

`QuickStartLobbyController` script:

```
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StartLobbyController : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
[SerializeField] GameObject quickStartButton;
[SerializeField] float roomSize;



public override void OnConnectedToMaster () {
    PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;
    quickStartButton.SetActive(true);
}

public void QuickStart () {
    quickStartButton.SetActive(false);
    PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();
    Debug.Log("Quick Start!");
}

public override void OnJoinRandomFailed (short returnCode, string message) {
    Debug.Log("Failed to join a room");
    CreateRoom();
}

public void CreateRoom () {
    Debug.Log("creating room");
    int randomRoomNumber = Random.Range(0, 10000);
    RoomOptions roomOps = new RoomOptions() { IsVisible = true, IsOpen = true, MaxPlayers = (byte)         
roomSize };
    PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom("Room" + randomRoomNumber, roomOps);
    Debug.Log(randomRoomNumber);
}

public override void OnCreateRoomFailed (short returnCode, string message) {
    Debug.Log("failed to create a room");
    CreateRoom();
}
}
```

`QuickStartRoomController` script :

```
using Photon.Pun;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RoomController : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
[SerializeField] int multiplayerSceneIndex;

public override void OnEnable () {
    PhotonNetwork.AddCallbackTarget(this);
}

public override void OnDisable () {
    PhotonNetwork.RemoveCallbackTarget(this);
}

public override void OnJoinedRoom () {
    Debug.Log("joined room");
    StartGame();
}

private void StartGame () {
    if ( PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient ) {
        Debug.Log("Starting game");
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(multiplayerSceneIndex);
    }
}
}
```

And now, the multiplayer scene where players should see each other:

[image: second item]

The player has those :

[image: preview 3]

The script inside `GameSetup`:

```
using Photon.Pun;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameSetupController : MonoBehaviour
{
 void Start()
 {
    CreatePlayer();
 }

private void CreatePlayer () {
     Debug.Log("Creating Player");
     PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs", "player"), Vector3.zero, 
 Quaternion.identity);
 }
 }
```

EDIT: so [here](https://youtu.be/YkXhiKFGWgc) you can see exactly how it looks like. When I play from the editor's window I can move around even if I can't see it, but with the client, I cannot do basically anything in-game. I think it might be a problem with the `GameSetup` code or with the part that syncs all the players with the server

EDIT2: posted the `playerController` script :

```
using Photon.Pun;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour, IPunObservable {
[SerializeField] Transform camera;
[SerializeField] float sens = 3.5f;
[SerializeField] float walkSpeed = 6.0f;
[SerializeField] [Range(0.0f, 0.5f)] float smooth = 0.3f;
[SerializeField] [Range(0.0f, 0.5f)] float smoothMouse = 0.3f;
[SerializeField] float gravity = -13.0f;
[SerializeField] float slopeForce = 6;
[SerializeField] float slopeForceRayLenght = 1.5f;
[SerializeField] float runSpeed = 10;
[SerializeField] float runBuildUp = 4;
[SerializeField] float jumpForce = 10;
[SerializeField] KeyCode jumpk;
[SerializeField] KeyCode runk;

[SerializeField] bool cursorLock = true;

public Rigidbody rb;
public Transform groundCheck;
public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
public LayerMask grndMask;

public bool isGrounded;

float cameraPitch = 0.0f;
float velocityY = 0.0f;
float speed;

Vector2 currentDir = Vector2.zero;
Vector2 currentDirVelocity = Vector2.zero;

Vector2 currentMouseDelta = Vector2.zero;
Vector2 currentMouseDeltaVelocity = Vector2.zero;

CharacterController controller;

PhotonView photonView;

private void Awake () {
    photonView = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    photonView.ObservedComponents.Add(this);
    if ( !photonView.IsMine ) {
        enabled = false;
    }
}
void Start () {
    speed = walkSpeed;

    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    if ( cursorLock ) {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    UpdateMouseLook();
    UpdateMovement();
    Jump();
}

void UpdateMouseLook () {
    Vector2 mouseDelta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse 
X"),Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));

    currentMouseDelta = Vector2.SmoothDamp(currentMouseDelta, mouseDelta,ref 
currentMouseDeltaVelocity, smoothMouse);

    cameraPitch -= currentMouseDelta.y * sens;

    cameraPitch = Mathf.Clamp(cameraPitch, -90.0f, 90.0f);
    camera.localEulerAngles = Vector3.right * cameraPitch;

    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * currentMouseDelta.x * sens);
}

void SetSpeed () {
    if ( Input.GetKey(runk) ) {
        speed = Mathf.Lerp(speed, runSpeed, Time.deltaTime * runBuildUp);
    } else {
        speed = Mathf.Lerp(speed, walkSpeed, Time.deltaTime * runBuildUp);
    }
}

void Jump () {
    isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, 
groundDistance,grndMask);
    if ( isGrounded && Input.GetKeyDown(jumpk) ) {
        Debug.Log("jumping");
        velocityY = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpForce * -2f * gravity);
        controller.Move(Vector3.up * velocityY * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

public bool OnSlope () {
    RaycastHit hit;

    if ( Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit, 
controller.height / 2 * slopeForceRayLenght) ) {
        if ( hit.normal != Vector3.up ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void UpdateMovement () {
    Vector2 inputDir = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"),
    Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    inputDir.Normalize();

    currentDir = Vector2.SmoothDamp(currentDir, inputDir, ref
    currentDirVelocity, smooth);

    if ( controller.isGrounded ) {
        velocityY = 0.0f;
    }
    velocityY += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    Vector3 velocity = (transform.forward * currentDir.y + transform.right * 
currentDir.x) * speed + Vector3.up * velocityY;

    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

    if ( (inputDir.x != 0 || inputDir.y != 0) && OnSlope() ) {
        controller.Move(Vector3.down * controller.height / 2 * slopeForce * 
Time.deltaTime);
    }
    SetSpeed();
}

void IPunObservable.OnPhotonSerializeView (PhotonStream stream, 
PhotonMessageInfo info) {
    if ( stream.IsWriting ) {

        // We own this player: send the others our data
        stream.SendNext(transform.position); //position of the character
        stream.SendNext(transform.rotation); //rotation of the character

    } else {
        // Network player, receive data
        Vector3 syncPosition = (Vector3) stream.ReceiveNext();
        Quaternion syncRotation = (Quaternion) stream.ReceiveNext();
    }
}
}
```

EDIT3: I found out something! When I enter the game from the master, I still need to drag myself up a bit in the editor and I will stop falling and I can play the game, but when the 2nd player connects, My camera is set to his (in all this time I can move my character and see this through the 2nd player's camera), and when he leaves all go back to normal on the master player. However, with the 2nd player, I can't move and I get an error that says:[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRJVS.png). Btw the 2nd player is the session from the standalone (the built game) and the first player is a session from the unity editor

Comment: Add box collider or mesh collider to ground

Comment: I have already added and I still fall. Only locally, cause if I look up in the `Scene` tab I see myself standing where I am supposed to

Comment: add collider wtith your player also

Comment: I still fall :(. I will make a video to show you how it looks

Comment: Yeah sue please do

Comment: ok I edited the initial question

Comment: Ok ok got I believe you have 2 player cloned sharing same script which is affecting both of them are you instantiating the players from script? If yes then make Y axis a little above as its -140 for also there are two cameras in the scene attached to both the players which can confuse unity which to render take a look at that also

Comment: You gonna uncheck fiedl `Is Kinematic`

Comment: So, I can see that when I play the game from the standalone and editor I have 3 players (2 of them are `clone`) so Should I delete the `player` from the scene and I will only have those 2 clones while playing?

Comment: As you can see I tried some synching in the `playerController` script I just posted now

Comment: I edited the post again with some additional infos